# Zero-width non-joiner can be shown in PyCharm but not in Spyder

Tags: python, pycharm, ascii, spyder

I have a python code as below

```
pri‌nt("good")
```

There is a zero-width non-joiner (i.e. ZWNJ) between the letters "i" and "n". If you copy the above code to PyCharm, you will see `pri[ZWNJ]nt("good")`. But if you copy the code to Spyder, you will only see `print("good")`. In both IDE, the code cannot be run and you will get an error.

The problem is more significant in Spyder, as the code looks normal, but cannot be run. Is possible to change the setting in Spyder so that `[ZWNJ]` can be shown?

Answer (score 1):

For VS Code there is this :
https://github.com/nhoizey/vscode-gremlins

Maybe you can find something similar for PyCharm. Otherwise why don't you just find and replace the command?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As explained in the question, for PyCharm there is no problem. The problem is only for Spyder as the ZWNJs don't show up.